# Difference Between JSTL and TLD

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

what is the Difference Between **

> JSTL

** and **

> TLD

** library files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSTL stays for
JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library
or Jsp Standard Tag Library.
They are a subset of classes packeged for using directly into jsp through <> tag.
[There are a series of already existent jstl immediate use.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnake.html)
Please refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) for a deep knowledge...

TLD stays for a xml document that describes a importing library and all tag within contained....
His use is widespread above validating tags used into a jsp page.
Please refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnamu.html) for a deep knowledge...